# cabal install wx Missing C library

Tags: haskell, cabal, wxhaskell

Env:

- OS: feodra 16
- haskell-platform
- wxGTK-devel
- ghc 7.0.4

I am trying to install wxHaskell with

> cabal install wx

Then these errors are given.

> Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
>   * Missing C libraries: wx_baseu-2.8, wx_baseu_net-2.8, wx_baseu_xml-2.8, wx_gtk2u_core-2.8, wx_gtk2u_adv-2.8,
>   wx_gtk2u_html-2.8, wx_gtk2u_qa-2.8, wx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8,
>   wx_gtk2u_aui-2.8, wx_gtk2u_richtext-2.8, wx_gtk2u_media-2.8,
>   wx_gtk2u_stc-2.8, wx_gtk2u_gl-2.8

And these libraries actually exist in /usr/lib
I type following in terminal

> ls libwx*.so

and found libs:

- libwx_baseu-2.8.so
- libwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8.so
- libwx_gtk2u_gl-2.8.so
- ......

I tried cabal install wx --exteral-lib-dirs=/usr/lib , but still no luck.

Comment: No .a files? Perhaps its looking to staticly link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the issue (and it only took me the best part of a month :))--you need to have `g++` installed on your machine. You can install it with `sudo yum install gcc-c++`.

Comment: thanks the error message is really misleading. With fedora I install gcc-c++ package and everything is ok!

Comment: Yeah. I spent forever trying out different library directories and stuff with no luck before seeing I needed g++. After that everything worked, which was anticlimactic.

Comment: Thank you again!!! I am seeking in the wx-core source code, but... with no lucky.

Comment: You can get the source (assuming you have the package already) using `cabal unpack wxcore`. If you want to see the source of a package without installing it, you can use `fetch`: `cabal fetch wxcore; cabal unpack wxcore`. However, you probably already have the package and don't need to fetch it.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a `wx` expert, but you likely additionally need the C headers for these libraries. Look for your distribution's "development" package for these libraries; in many distributions, these packages are named the same as the library package itself, but with "-dev" added at the end of the name.

Comment: On Fedora these packages are called *-devel. jilen seems to have the wxGTK-devel package installed.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-media3.0-dev
```

works for me

Comment: This command helps tremendously! I got stuck on this for a long time and installing `libwxgtk-media3.0-dev` solves my C library dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution, but I hit the exact same problem last night on a fresh Debian Wheezy install, which makes me think that it might be a packaging problem with the wx in cabal.