# Haskell cabal install wx: missing C library wx_gtk2u_webview-3.0

Tags: haskell, cabal, wxhaskell

I am trying to install wx by `cabal install wx`

```
Configuring wxc to build against wxWidgets 3.0
setup: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: wx_gtk2u_webview-3.0
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install :
wx-0.92.0.0 depends on wxc-0.92.0.0 which failed to install.
wxc-0.92.0.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
wxcore-0.92.0.0 depends on wxc-0.92.0.0 which failed to install.
```

but I have following files in `/usr/lib` :

```
/usr/lib/libwx_gtk2u_webview-3.0.so
/usr/lib/libwx_gtk2u_webview-3.0.so.0
/usr/lib/libwx_gtk2u_webview-3.0.so.0.2.0
```

I have also tried `cabal install --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib/ wx` but to no avail.

I have also tried all the suggestions in [cabal install wx Missing C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756088/cabal-install-wx-missing-c-library)

I am on archlinux and I have both wxgtk-3.0 and wxgtk-2.8 multilib and normal versions. I also tried reinstalling them.

Comment: you could give Stackage/`stack` a try — it is able to take a `.cabal` file and compute a working set of dependencies, based on the GHC/LTS Stackage/Nightly version you specify. I was able to get some sample code that depends on WX to build without hassle on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem on Arch; when I tried running cabal with `--verbose=3`, it looked like `libwx_gtk2u_webview-3.0` was present, but it was complaining about `libwebkitgtk-1.0` being missing. After I installed the `webkitgtk2` package, which provides `libwebkitgtk-1.0`, wxHaskell installed with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try "sudo apt-get install libwxgtk-webview3.0-dev". It worked for me.